# What is authenticity of this hadith? Reference: Imam Bayhaqi in his Dalail an Nabuwwah: Volume 005, Page No. 483

Tags: hadith, authenticity

Abu Hurraira (May Allah have mercy on him) narrates from the Messenger of Allah (Peace be on him) that he said: When Allah created Adam (Peace be upon him) He informed him of his descendants, at this Adam (Peace be upon him) saw superiority of some over others, then he saw me towards the end in form of an “ILLUMINATING NUR”. Adam (Peace be on him) said: O my Lord who is this? The Lord replied: This is your son Ahmed who is the first and the last and (on the Day of Judgment) he will be first to do intercession.

Comment: Not an answer but a similar Hadith is found [here](https://sunnah.com/mishkat:122).